# Can't store dataframe date columns with format %Y.%m.%d

Tags: python, pandas, date-formatting

I'm trying to store a dataframe as csv. I want the datecolumns to be stored in format `'%Y.%m.%d'`. For some reason it seems the data is always stored in the format `'%Y-%m-%d'`.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

DATE_FORMAT = '%Y.%m.%d'

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': [1.5, 2.3, 3.5],
                   'Date_Col': [date(2019, 1, 1), date(2019, 2, 1), date(2019, 3, 1)]})

df.to_csv('df.csv', index=False, decimal=',', sep=';', date_format=DATE_FORMAT)
```

The resulting csv file looks like this

```
Col;Date_Col
1,5;2019-01-01
2,3;2019-02-01
3,5;2019-03-01
```

I have checked that `DATE_FORMAT` is a valid format

```
print(date(2019, 2, 1).strftime(DATE_FORMAT))
2019.02.01
```

What is going on and how can I get the correct output? I get that I can cast all the date-columns to strings, but I would rather not use this approach as I need the dataframe at some other point in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution working if values are `datetimes`, not python object dates:

Python dates in pandas now (pandas 0.24+) working, but still some limitations/bugs.

```
df['Date_Col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Col'])
a = df.to_csv(index=False, decimal=',', sep=';', date_format=DATE_FORMAT)
print (a)
Col;Date_Col
1,5;2019.01.01
2,3;2019.02.01
3,5;2019.03.01
```